# User research unstructured data aggregation tool

Tags: database, user-experience, nosql

we've started to do a user research to better understand our users. However, the data that we collect isn't well structured - it's interviews and observations reports rather than statistical analytics data. From what we've collected so far, the data has several dimensions : type of user, workflows performed by the user, the problems that the user encounters etc. We are looking for a tool to store this data efficiently and perform mining on it to know where to focus our solution efforts.

Does anybody knows what tool / set of tools can be used for it?

Maybe somebody has certain techniques to organize that sort of data.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by organization of that data? Since the data is not structured, you will have to go with nosql database. Now if you want to perform searching over it, I would suggest you Elasticsearch. If you are going to just store it , you can use Mongo, Couch, Cassandra etc. as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout Jupyter notebook http://jupyter.org
Pretty powerful tool